# How to fix compile errors on chrono when upgrade project from VS2010 to 2015

Tags: c++, mfc, upgrade, c++-chrono

I try to upgrade a project from VC2010 to VC2015.
And I got some compile errors.
I have solved some of that.
There are some error remains.
That error occurred on the chrono source of VC2015.
I can't find how to fix that.

Is there any change about C++ syntax?
How to fix the errors.

Below is the error messages.
I got about 6000 errors. But I remove duplicated.
I added the chrono source code.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   C2332   'class': missing tag name   MyProject_VS2015    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\chrono   384
Error   C2993   '': illegal type for non-type template parameter '<unnamed-tag>'    MyProject_VS2015    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\chrono   384
Error   C2059   syntax error: 'string'  MyProject_VS2015    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\chrono   384
Error   C2974   'std::is_convertible': invalid template argument for '_To', type expected   MyProject_VS2015    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\chrono   387
Error   C2955   'std::is_convertible': use of class template requires template argument list    MyProject_VS2015    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\chrono   387
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '{'    MyProject_VS2015    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\chrono   389
Error   C2447   '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)   MyProject_VS2015    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\chrono   389
Error   C2332   'class': missing tag name   MyProject_VS2015    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\chrono   393
Error   C2993   '': illegal type for non-type template parameter '<unnamed-tag>'    MyProject_VS2015    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\chrono   393
Error   C2059   syntax error: 'string'  MyProject_VS2015    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\chrono   393
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '{'    MyProject_VS2015    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\chrono   397
Error   C2447   '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)   MyProject_VS2015    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\chrono   397
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ',' before '<'    MyProject_VS2015    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\chrono   412
Error   C2518   keyword 'typename' illegal in base class list; ignored  MyProject_VS2015    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\chrono   412
Error   C2976   'std::chrono::_Duration_div_mod': too few template arguments    MyProject_VS2015    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\chrono   420
Error   C2144   syntax error: 'int' should be preceded by ';'   MyProject_VS2015    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\chrono   421
Error   C2433   'type': 'inline' not permitted on data declarations MyProject_VS2015    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\chrono   421
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    MyProject_VS2015    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\chrono   421
Error   C2065   '_Rep1': undeclared identifier  MyProject_VS2015    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\chrono   422
Error   C2065   '_Period1': undeclared identifier   MyProject_VS2015    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\chrono   422
Error   C2923   'std::chrono::duration': '_Rep1' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Rep' MyProject_VS2015    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\chrono   422
Error   C2923   'std::chrono::duration': '_Period1' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Period'   MyProject_VS2015    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\chrono   422
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    MyProject_VS2015    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\chrono   423
Error   C2988   unrecognizable template declaration/definition  MyProject_VS2015    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\chrono   423
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ',' before '&'    MyProject_VS2015    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\chrono   423


C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\chrono
384 template<class _CR,
385     class _Period1,
386     class _Rep2,
387     bool = is_convertible<_Rep2, _CR>::value>
388     struct _Duration_div_mod1
389     {   // return type for duration / rep and duration % rep
390     typedef duration<_CR, _Period1> type;
391     };
392 
393 template<class _CR,
394     class _Period1,
395     class _Rep2>
396     struct _Duration_div_mod1<_CR, _Period1, _Rep2, false>
397     {   // no return type
398     };


408 template<class _Rep1,
409     class _Period1,
410     class _Rep2>
411     struct _Duration_div_mod<_Rep1, _Period1, _Rep2, false>
412         : _Duration_div_mod1<typename common_type<_Rep1, _Rep2>::type,
413             _Period1, _Rep2>
414     {   // return type for duration / rep and duration % rep
415     };
416 
417 template<class _Rep1,
418     class _Period1,
419     class _Rep2> inline
420     typename _Duration_div_mod<_Rep1, _Period1, _Rep2>::type
421         constexpr operator/(
422             const duration<_Rep1, _Period1>& _Left,
423             const _Rep2& _Right)
424     {   // divide duration by rep
425     typedef typename common_type<_Rep1, _Rep2>::type _CR;
426     typedef duration<_CR, _Period1> _CD;
427     return (_CD(_CD(_Left).count() / _Right));
428     }
```

Comment: First guess:  macro nastiness.  I would inspect the preprocessed source and see what `_CR` got expanded to.

Comment: @HowardHinnant Thanks. It solved. My project has other definition for _CR. I changed my definition.

Comment: Macros starting with _ and a capital letter are reserved for use by the compiler/standard library and your code shouldn't contain any of them to prevent issues like this one